# Create Pydantic model with SQLAlchemy with different name of fields

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pydantic

In case I have next SQLAlchemy model:

```
    __tablename__ = 'run_dir'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    path = Column(String(1024))
    session_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('session.id'))
    session = relationship('Session', backref='run_dirs') 

class Session(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'run_dir'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(1024))
    last_time_run =  Column(String(1024))
```

I want my Pydantic model field to have different names,
and have the fields from the ForeignKey for example:

```
class RunDir(BaseModel):
    run_dir_id: int
    path_to_dir: str
    run_session_last_time: int
    session_name: str
```

how I can do this?

Comment: The values should be int and str, but more important is the names

Comment: [RTFM](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/models/#reserved-names)

Answer (score 0):

You can include `Field` from the Pydantic -

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
```

And then you can define your class -

```
class RunDir(BaseModel):
    run_dir_id: int = Field(..., alias='id')
    path_to_dir: str = Field(..., alias='path')
    run_session_last_time: int = Field(..., alias='session_last_time')
    session_name: str = Field(..., alias='session_name')
```

Please refer to this [doc](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/models/#orm-mode-aka-arbitrary-class-instances) for calling the Pydantic model.

Comment: what should be the call line to convert it?

Comment: You can Pydantic base model function - `from_orm`:
`model = RunDir.from_orm(instnace_of_SQLAlchemy_model)`